# How do I fix this error in my double loop?

Tags: python, loops, numpy

I am trying to compute the following:

[image: E_inc_j]

[image: tilde{k}]

```
def E_inc_j(tilde_k, x, vecinc):
    n = x.shape[0]
    e = np.zeros((n, 3))

    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(3):
            e[i] = np.exp(1j * tilde_k * x[i]) * vecinc

    return e

def x(n):
    return np.random.randint(100, size=(n, 3))

lam = 0.5
k = (2 * np.pi)/lam
theta = 0
K = k * np.array([[0], [np.sin(theta)], [np.cos(theta)]])
vecinc = np.array([[1], [0], [0]])

E_inc_j_test = E_inc_j(K, x(5), vecinc) 
print(E_inc_j_test)
```

I am getting the error "could not broadcast input array from shape (3,3) into shape (3)" at the line `e[i] = np.exp(1j * tilde_k * x[i]) * vecinc`.

***** The end result should be a 3N by 1 vector. *****

Comment: Please add the desired output for a given input, also do you have a picture of the equation you are trying to do?

Comment: @Error - Syntactical Remorse Sure. I corrected my K and vecinc vectors (they were row vectors instead of column vectors, my mistake) and now I am getting the error above. The result should be a pretty random looking n by 3 complex vector.

Comment: `k` and `theta` are undefined

Comment: @Error - Syntactical Remorse Oops! I meant a 3n by 1 vector.

Comment: @Nils Werner Oops, sorry. I added them.

Comment: Is that a dot product between e and the 1,0,0 vector?

Comment: @Nils Werner Maybe? Should it be?

Comment: I don't know, it's your formula. Please provide input and expected output data.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a for loop at all:

```
import numpy as np

k = 10.
theta = 0.3
K = k * np.array([0, np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta)])

x = np.random.randint(100, size=(7, 3))
vecinc = np.array([1, 0, 0])

e = np.exp(1j * K * x) * vecinc
# array([[ 1.+0.j,  0.+0.j,  0.-0.j],
#        [ 1.+0.j,  0.-0.j,  0.-0.j],
#        [ 1.+0.j,  0.+0.j,  0.+0.j],
#        [ 1.+0.j,  0.-0.j, -0.+0.j],
#        [ 1.+0.j,  0.+0.j, -0.+0.j],
#        [ 1.+0.j,  0.-0.j,  0.+0.j],
#        [ 1.+0.j, -0.+0.j, -0.+0.j]])
```

Comment: Hmmmm, not really what I'm looking for. More like a 3N by 1 vector. Sorry I was not more clear, I just got some new information so I hope my new edits clarify :)